# How trigger limits are counted in web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a web app that creates a process that can take well above 6 min to complete. I have decided to chunk it out using timed triggers and scriptDB to track execution process.

I have my web app shared within our organization, to execute as the user accessing it.

Are the script triggers created as the user, or as the script-owner in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If your script is set to execute as the user accesing it, then the triggers are created under the user's account and not the  owner of the script.